# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'ponto'

Tags: python

This is my  full code and i got this error too:

line 176, in get_ponto_local
matriz_local=matriz * matriz_ponto
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Matriz' and 'Matriz'

class Camara:

```
def __init__(self, posicao, olhar_para, vertical,
             distancia_olho_plano_projecao, largura_retangulo_projecao,
             altura_retangulo_projecao, resolucao_horizontal,
             resolucao_vertical,ponto):

    self.posicao = posicao
    self.olhar_para = olhar_para
    self.vertical = vertical.versor()
    self.distancia_olho_plano_projecao = distancia_olho_plano_projecao
    self.largura_retangulo_projecao = largura_retangulo_projecao
    self.altura_retangulo_projecao = altura_retangulo_projecao
    self.resolucao_horizontal = resolucao_horizontal
    self.resolucao_vertical = resolucao_vertical

    eixo_z = (olhar_para - posicao).versor()
    self.eixo_z = eixo_z

    eixo_y = self.vertical
    eixo_y =  (vertical + eixo_z * (-1.0 * vertical.interno(eixo_z)))
    self.eixo_y = eixo_y.versor()

    eixo_x = eixo_z.externo(eixo_y)
    self.eixo_x = eixo_x

    incremento_horizontal = largura_retangulo_projecao/resolucao_horizontal
    incremento_vertical = altura_retangulo_projecao/resolucao_vertical

    canto_superior_esquerdo_x = -largura_retangulo_projecao/2.0 \
        + incremento_horizontal/2.0
    canto_superior_esquerdo_y = altura_retangulo_projecao/2.0 \
        - incremento_vertical/2.0
    canto_superior_esquerdo_z = distancia_olho_plano_projecao

    self.incremento_horizontal = incremento_horizontal
    self.incremento_vertical = incremento_vertical

    self.canto_superior_esquerdo_x = canto_superior_esquerdo_x
    self.canto_superior_esquerdo_y = canto_superior_esquerdo_y
    self.canto_superior_esquerdo_z = canto_superior_esquerdo_z

    matriz = Matriz(4,4)

    matriz.set_entrada(1, 1, eixo_x.get_x())
    matriz.set_entrada(2, 1, eixo_x.get_y())
    matriz.set_entrada(3, 1, eixo_x.get_z())

    matriz.set_entrada(1, 2, eixo_y.get_x())
    matriz.set_entrada(2, 2, eixo_y.get_y())
    matriz.set_entrada(3, 2, eixo_y.get_z())

    matriz.set_entrada(1, 3, eixo_z.get_x())
    matriz.set_entrada(2, 3, eixo_z.get_y())
    matriz.set_entrada(3, 3, eixo_z.get_z())

    matriz.set_entrada(1, 4, posicao.get_x())
    matriz.set_entrada(2, 4, posicao.get_y())
    matriz.set_entrada(3, 4, posicao.get_z())
    matriz.set_entrada(4, 4, 1.0) # porque é um ponto

    self.matriz = matriz

    #Matriz_inversa de mudança
    self.matriz_mudança=matriz.transposta()


    #Matriz prespectiva
    matriz2=Matriz(4,4)
    matriz2.set_entrada(1,1,distancia_olho_plano_projecao)
    matriz2.set_entrada(1,2,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(1,3,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(1,4,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(2,1,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(2,2,distancia_olho_plano_projecao)
    matriz2.set_entrada(2,3,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(2,4,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(3,1,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(3,2,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(3,3,distancia_olho_plano_projecao)
    matriz2.set_entrada(3,4,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(4,1,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(4,2,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(4,3,0)
    matriz2.set_entrada(4,4,distancia_olho_plano_projecao)
    self.matriz_prespectiva=matriz2 










def __str__(self):
    #Retorna uma string com os atributos do objeto do tipo Camara.


    return("Camara("
           + str(self.posicao)  + ",\n"
           + str(self.olhar_para) + ",\n"
           + str(self.vertical) + ",\n"
           + str(self.distancia_olho_plano_projecao) + ",\n"
           + str(self.largura_retangulo_projecao) + ",\n"
           + str(self.altura_retangulo_projecao) + ",\n"
           + str(self.resolucao_horizontal) + ",\n"
           + str(self.resolucao_vertical) + ",\n"
           + str(self.eixo_x) + ",\n"
           + str(self.eixo_y) + ",\n"
           + str(self.eixo_z) + ",\n"
           + str(self.incremento_horizontal) + ",\n"
           + str(self.incremento_vertical) + ",\n"
           + str(self.canto_superior_esquerdo_x) + ",\n"
           + str(self.canto_superior_esquerdo_y) + ",\n"
           + str(self.canto_superior_esquerdo_z) + ",\n"
           + str(self.Matriz)
           + ")")


def get_resoluçao_vertical(self):
    return self.resolucao_vertical

def get_resolucao_horizontal(self):
    return self.resoluçao_horizontal




def get_pixel_local(self, linha, coluna):
    """Retorna o Ponto3D na linha e coluna do plano de projeção
    especificados pelos argumentos, no sistema de coordenadas
    local da câmara."""


    pixel_x = self.canto_superior_esquerdo_x \
        + (coluna-1)*self.incremento_horizontal
    pixel_y = self.canto_superior_esquerdo_y \
        - (linha-1)*self.incremento_vertical
    pixel_z = self.canto_superior_esquerdo_z

    return(Ponto3D(pixel_x, pixel_y, pixel_z))





def get_ponto_local(self,ponto_global):
    """Converte o sistema de coodernadas global para o sistema
    de coodernadas da camara"""

    matriz_ponto=Matriz(4,1)

    matriz_ponto.set_entrada(1,1,ponto_global.x)
    matriz_ponto.set_entrada(2,1,ponto_global.y)
    matriz_ponto.set_entrada(3,1,ponto_global.z)
    matriz_ponto.set_entrada(4,1,0.0)

    matriz=self.matriz



    matriz_para_mudança=self.matriz_mudança


    matriz_local=matriz * matriz_ponto
    x=matriz_local.get_entrada(1,1)
    y=matriz_local.get_entrada(2,1)
    z=matriz_local.get_entrada(3,1)

    return Ponto3D(x,y,z)


#def local_para_global(self, ponto):
    """Converte o Ponto3D ponto do sistema de coordendas da câmara
    para o sistema de coordenads global.
    """

""" local_x = ponto.get_x()
    local_y = ponto.get_y()
    local_z = ponto.get_z()

    p = Matriz(4,1)

    p.set_entrada(1, 1, local_x)
    p.set_entrada(2, 1, local_y)
    p.set_entrada(3, 1, local_z)
    p.set_entrada(4, 1, 1.0) # porque é um ponto

    p_transformado = self.matriz * p

    global_x = p_transformado.get_entrada(1, 1)
    global_y = p_transformado.get_entrada(2, 1)
    global_z = p_transformado.get_entrada(3, 1)

    return Ponto3D(global_x, global_y, global_z)

    """
```

## testes

if **name** == "**main**":

```
# teste ao construtor
posicao    = Ponto3D(0.0, 0.0, 3.0)
olhar_para = Ponto3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
vertical   = Vector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
distancia_olho_plano_projecao = 2.0
largura_retangulo_projecao    = 2.0
altura_retangulo_projecao     = 2.0
resolucao_horizontal          = 5
resolucao_vertical            = 5
ponto=0.0

camara = Camara(posicao, olhar_para, vertical, distancia_olho_plano_projecao,
                largura_retangulo_projecao, altura_retangulo_projecao,
                resolucao_horizontal, resolucao_vertical,ponto)

# teste a __str__
print(Camara)

# teste a get_pixel_local
print("sistema de coordenadas LOCAL")
print("canto superior esquerdo = ")
p1 = camara.get_pixel_local(1,1)
print(p1)
print("canto superior direito = ")
p2 = camara.get_pixel_local(1,5)
print(p2)
print("canto inferior esquerdo = ")
p3 = camara.get_pixel_local(5,1)
print(p3)
print("canto inferioror direito = ")
p4 = camara.get_pixel_local(5,5)
print(p4)

#teste matriz_inversa
matriz=Matriz(4,4)
matriz_mudança=matriz.transposta()
print("Matriz inversa de mudnaça")
print(matriz_mudança)

#teste matriz_prespectiva
matriz2=Matriz(4,4)
matriz_prespectiva=matriz2
MP=matriz_prespectiva
print("Matriz prespectiva")
print(MP)

#teste a get_ponto_global
print(camara.get_ponto_local(Ponto3D(-2.0,5.0,4.0)))

#teste a local_para_global
"""
print("sistema de coordenadas GLOBAL")
print("canto superior esquerdo = ")
p1_global = camara.local_para_global(p1)
print(p1_global)
print("canto superior direito = ")
p2_global = camara.local_para_global(p2)
print(p2_global)
print("canto inferior esquerdo = ")
p3_global = camara.local_para_global(p3)
print(p3_global)
print("canto inferioror direito = ")
p4_global = camara.local_para_global(p4)
print(p4_global)"""
```

Error:

```
 p1_global = Camara.local_para_global(p1)
TypeError: local_para_global() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ponto
```

Comment: Is `local_para_global()` a member function of a class or is it a free function?

Comment: member function of a class

Comment: Can you post your full code? It's hard to troubleshoot based on what you've supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an *instance* of your `Camara` class.

As it is you are calling `local_para_global()` as if it were a class method of class `Camara`.

Something like this should fix it:

```
camara = Camara(...)    # instantiate an object of class Camara
p1_global = camara.local_para_global(p1)
```

You will need to replace the `...` above with the parameters required to instantiate a `Camara`.

Comment: Well, you do need to instantiate the class before you can call it's bound methods. Is `local_para_global()` a method defined in _class_ `Camara`? If yes then you need to create an instance of the `Camara` class. Otherwise, your definition of  `local_para_global()`  is incorrect, and it does not require the `self` parameter.